# How to do a complex LEFT JOIN condition in JPQL?

Tags: playframework, left-join, jpql

I am using JPQL for the model queries from Play Framework.

I wonder if JPQL supports "complex" ON condition for LEFT JOIN.

In an example I have, there are 2 tables:

- 'App' - list of applications
- 'AggregationHistory' - the list of the aggregation records per application, per date. In the model, it has 'app' field representing
  many-to-one with 'App' (column name 'app_id' in the physical table)

Suppose I want to calculate the list of all the apps that **do not** have a record for a specific date.

In plain SQL, I get the result using the following query:

```
SELECT a.* FROM app a LEFT JOIN aggregationhistory ah 
ON a.id = ah.app_id AND ah.fromDate =  '2012-03-14 00:00:00' 
WHERE ah.fromDate is NULL
```

'AND' in 'ON' condition is essential, of course.

Now, all the examples of JPQL I see are like:

```
SELECT a.* FROM AggregationHistory ah  LEFT JOIN ah.app a WHERE ...
```

So, the only 'ON' condition supported - is the "match" of the IDs? (WHERE seems not to help me much)

I can think of workarounds (like, using a "native query", or using JOIN to get the list of the applications that **do have** a record, and compare). But I wonder if the query I made in SQL - can be converted into JPQL.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

JPQL, AFAIK, doesn't support `ON` clauses, but HQL does support them. The chose to use the `with` keyword though:

```
select a from App a 
left join a.history h with h.fromDate = :fromDate
where h.fromDate is null
```

Comment: Thanks. Just one thing to clarify... In the current model, I don't have 'a.history' - just 'ah.app' . I tried to get it done via: FROM AggregationHistory ah RIGHT JOIN ah.app a WITH ah.fromDate = :fromDate . Unfortunately getting: InvalidWithClauseException: with-clause expressions did not reference from-clause element to which the with-clause was associated. Looks like WITH expects to use 'a' and not 'ah' . The only solution is to add 'a.history'? Thanks

Comment: Honestly, I don't know. But having bidirectional associations tremendously help formulating queries in general, and are thus useful even if never used (or even exposed) in the object model.