# Join in play framework

Tags: html, sql, jpa, playframework, jpa-2.0

i have never use jpa and i would like to ask if there is a join

if i do this

```
String queryStringGet="SELECT c.* FROM Category c "+

"LEFT JOIN User us ON us.id = c.id "+

"+"WHERE c.user_id="+id;

List<Object[]> list = JPA.em().createNativeQuery(queryString).getResultList();
```

Works but comes out as an object, and i don't know how to list in the view :(

Since play.db.jpa.Model  does not suport ON how do i do a join ?
and how do i List the objects?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

JPQL doesn't support joins. There is an [explanation of how to do it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9710252/how-to-do-a-complex-left-join-condition-in-jpql).

And you can get the results in a List like so:

```
String hql = "SELECT c FROM Category c "
           + "LEFT JOIN User us WITH us.id = c.id "
           + "WHERE c.user_id= :userId";
Query query = JPA.em().createQuery(hql, Categories.class);
query.setParameter("userId", userId);
List<Category> categories = query.getResultList();
```

Comment: this is not working in play framework

IllegalArgumentException occured : org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting IDENT, found '*' near line 1, column 10[SELECT c.* FROM Category c LEFT JOIN User us WITH us.id = c.id WHERE c.user_id= :userId ]

Answer (score 1):

Try to read this ;)

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a native query, it will run correctly as long as the sql is valid on your database.

With a custom query, this code will return a list of array of objects with the implicit datatype. So if the first column you return is a varchar, object[0] will be a string. You will have to do the mapping to your object yourself

```
    List<Category> categories = query.getResultList();
    Category cat = null;
    for (Object[] objects : categories ) {
        if (cat == null)
            cat = new Category();
        cat.name = (String) objects[0];
        ...
    }
```