# Why am I getting exception in JPQL join query using toplink?

Tags: jpa, left-join, jpql

The following is the exception message I am getting when I run this query.
Kindly tell what is the error ?

Query:

```
select w.tagName,w.tagDescription, f.chosenDate from TagEntity w LEFT JOIN TagFavouriteEntity f ON w.tagId=f.tagId
```

Exception:

```
Syntax error parsing the query [select w.tagName,w.tagDescription, f.chosenDate from TagEntity w LEFT JOIN TagFavouriteEntity f ON w.tagId=f.tagId], line 1, column 95: syntax     error at [f].
Internal Exception: line 1:95: expecting DOT, found 'f'
```

I have two entities : TagEntity and TagFavoriteEntity.
There is no relation between them. Only one attribute "tagId" is common between them which is also the primary key of TagEntity class.

Comment: @ noc2spam I have updated the question. Sorry for not writing the query clearly. It was in the exception message only

Comment: AFAIK JPQL does not support ON. See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/9710344/1437261  . Disclaimer.. I am from LAMP background and have no prior experience in jpa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JPQL is not SQL. That's not how joins are expressed in JPQL. JPQL uses associations between entities. You didn't post your entities, so let's imagine you have an `Order` entity having a OneToMany association `lines` with a `Line` entity, a proper JPQL join would look like this:

```
select o.id, l.id from Order o left join o.lines l
```

Comment: My both the Entities are separate having no relation with each other. Can I not apply a join in that case ? Only "tagId" is an attribute which is primary key in TagEntity and also a part of TagFavoriteEntity

Comment: I want to join 2 independent entities. What should I do in this case ?

Comment: With a left join, you can't. You'll have to use SQL.

Comment: Kindly tell me how can I do it in JPQL ?

Comment: As I said, you can't. You'll have to use SQL.